# Android Location - Network provider, device speed

Tags: android, networking, location, location-provider

Is it possible to get the device speed from the location NETWORK_PROVIDER and not from the GPS_PROVIDER?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by device speed do you mean how fast the device is travelling?

if so, then the short answer is no.

longer answer is, that the way network provider works it has no reliable way of telling where the device is relative to the cell tower it is connected to, and therefor wouldn't be able to calculate speed even when the device switches from one cell tower to another.

for more information about how the location providers work look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6775456/744610).