# Android LocationManager is it more resource intensive to get the longitude and latitude from NETWORK_PROVIDER or GPS_PROVIDER?

Tags: android

Which method of retrieving the longitude and latitude from the LocationManager is the most resource intensive, from `NETWORK_PROVIDER or GPS_PROVIDER?`

Comment: get location by using best provider !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GPS consume more resources than Network provider. Take a look at this answer to more details.

[Android Location Providers - GPS or Network Provider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775257/android-location-providers-gps-or-network-provider)