# How to get better accuracy using Network Provider.

Tags: android, location

I have developed an app. It tells my current location using Network Provider.
But the accuracy is not that good. But other apps like "Foursquare" or "Hangout" can tell my current location using only Network Provider pretty accurately. How these apps do it? Is there anyway to improve accuracy using network provider?

Comment: See if this helps, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775257/android-location-providers-gps-or-network-provider