# There is no response from requestLocationUpdates

Tags: android

Here I am trying to get location details. For that i used both `GPS_PROVIDER` and `NETWORK_PROVIDER` and both are in enable mode only. My problem is, I do not get any response in `LocationListener`.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    private TextView mTxtTodayDate;
    private Button mBtnShowTodayDate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mTxtTodayDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTodayDate);
        mBtnShowTodayDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowTodayDate);
        mBtnShowTodayDate.setOnClickListener(mShowDateListener);
    }

    private LocationListener gpsProvider= new LocationListener() {

         @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                switch (status) {
                case LocationProvider.AVAILABLE:
                    mTxtTodayDate.setText( "GPS available again\n");
                    break;
                case LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE:
                    mTxtTodayDate.setText( "GPS out of service\n");
                    break;
                case LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
                    mTxtTodayDate.setText("GPS temporarily unavailable\n");
                    break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                mTxtTodayDate.setText("GPS Provider Enabled\n");
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                mTxtTodayDate.setText("GPS Provider Disabled\n");
            }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Log.v("MainActivity", "Location Changed in location listener");
            mTxtTodayDate.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale
                    .getDefault()).format(new Date(location.getTime())));
        }
    };

    private LocationListener networkProvider = new LocationListener() {

         @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                switch (status) {
                case LocationProvider.AVAILABLE:
                    mTxtTodayDate.setText( "NETWORK PROVIDER available again\n");
                    break;
                case LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE:
                    mTxtTodayDate.setText( "NETWORK PROVIDER out of service\n");
                    break;
                case LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
                    mTxtTodayDate.setText("NETWORK PROVIDER temporarily unavailable\n");
                    break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                mTxtTodayDate.setText("NETWORK PROVIDER Provider Enabled\n");
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                mTxtTodayDate.setText("NETWORK PROVIDER Provider Disabled\n");
            }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Log.v("MainActivity", "Location Changed in location listener");
            mTxtTodayDate.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale
                    .getDefault()).format(new Date(location.getTime())));
        }
    };

    private OnClickListener mShowDateListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getDate();
        }
    };

    private void getDate(){
        Log.v("MainActivity", "getDate()");
        LocationManager locationManager=(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        boolean flag = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        boolean flag1 = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        Log.v("MainActivity", "NETWORK_PROVIDER Enabled: "+flag+" GSP:"+flag1);

        if(!flag && !flag1){
            Builder  dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            dialog.setMessage("Activate location listener" );
             dialog.setPositiveButton("Setting", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


                 @Override
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS), 100);
                     paramDialogInterface.dismiss();
                 }
             });
             dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                 @Override
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int paramInt) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     dialog.dismiss();
                 }
             });
             dialog.show();

        }else{
            Log.v("MainActivity", "Provider enabled");
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, networkProvider);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, gpsProvider);
    }
}
```

I added below permission in manifest,

```
<uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

I am doing this location listener to get current day's date only, because my project fully related with date. But application user changing date and hacking my application functions. To avoid this i am planned to get current day's date from `Location`. Here I **strickly** do not want to use `INTERNET` to get current day's date. If have any idea regarding this please share with me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you given INTERNET permission too ?

Comment: yeah already tried with INTERNET permission but not works

Comment: Are you trying in emulator ?

Comment: no in real device only. I really confused. Do GPS_PROVIDER and NETWORK_PROVIDER requires INTERNET permission?. Pls look at it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775257/android-location-providers-gps-or-network-provider

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. Just for your information, as per your coding, it will use GPS_PROVIDER.

Comment: @Satish, Yes INTERNET Permission is must. I neg late it and spend two day to find error in my code.

Comment: oh thank you, did you look at end of my question?

Comment: Yes, I read it already. But keep in mind that with out INTERNET permission you can't get the Location service.

Comment: so this not going to help for my date issue. Let i think on some other possibilities.

Comment: Your project's validation expires on some date, User can set previous date and access your application again. That's your problem right ?

Comment: yeah but not for project it is for product. I need to do some calculation depends on offer date of product.

Comment: Well you track date change event using BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: yeah this is the final solution in our hand. Sure I will do with this.

Comment: That's good. Have a nice evening. See ya

Comment: Thank you for good guidance. Enjoy the cool evening.