# How does Automatic date and time work in Android?

Tags: android, datetime

For some date-based calculation I needed today's correct date, for which I enabled `Automatic date and time` option in `Date and Time Settings` and this gives me the correct time and date.

I want to know how Android gets the correct date and time, even though I have not enabled any internet accessibility (WiFi, SIM Data).

Also look at this: [There is no response from requestLocationUpdates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22837212/there-is-no-response-from-requestlocationupdates)

Please give me some reference on this.

Comment: It's likely that it's just adjusting your timezone based on GPS positioning, which doesn't require data connectivity.

Comment: Do you have any code related this, because yesterday i fully tried to gettime using GPS positioning but not get succeeded. Pls Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22837212/there-is-no-response-from-requestlocationupdates?noredirect=1#comment34835678_22837212

Answer (score 0):

It capture date and time from the network provider. not only android lots of other phone can do the same.
   Autometic date time is provided be the network provide (exmp: vodafone,airtel etc etc ).

Comment: Can I able to get date and time from network provider like android doing?

Comment: I don't think so you have to  call the new Date(System.currentmilliseceond)