# Do i need phone location enabled ( api >19) to get coarse location( Network provider) ?

Tags: android, location

Do i need phone location enabled ( api >19 ,lolipop and marshmallow) to get coarse location( network provider) ? I searched for a clear answer but i still do not get it. I cant get my location on google maps. I wonder if i get my location with coarse location do i still need the location enable ( Not gps enable from older phones <19 ) with coarse location permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can refer [[Android Location Providers - GPS or Network Provider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775257/android-location-providers-gps-or-network-provider]). 
Phone location (gps) requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION. If ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION is used, the location will be retrieved from network provider only.
And I think no new change has been made in API above 19.