# Using only GPS, without WiFi or Network Data

Tags: android, gps, location, wifi, batterylevel

I wanna optimise battery consumption. And use the only GPS instead of invoking WiFi. When I'm using ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION Wifi scan is performed. Can I switch off this scan somehow?

Comment: you can select the location providers you want to use (but i don't remember how to, you'll have to search for it)

Comment: You might be able to find what you need on this question about location providers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775257/android-location-providers-gps-or-network-provider