# Broadcast receiver onReceive fires twice on location change

Tags: android, kotlin, observable, android-broadcastreceiver

I want to know whenever user turn his gps off. I want to get informed about that action in different activities. I made Broadcast Receiver to listen for GPS state change. But almost always when i turn off GPS, my updateValue function get fired twice. How to get notified one time, when user turn his gps off? What i did wrong? Below is my code.

```
class GpsStatusReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
var observableGpsState: ObservableGpsState? = null

override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
    val locationManager = context?.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
    if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        //GPS Turned on,OK..
    } else {
        if (observableGpsState == null)
            observableGpsState = ObservableGpsState.getInstance()
        observableGpsState?.updateValue(GPS_STATUS_TURNED_OFF)
    }
}

companion object {
    val GPS_STATUS_TURNED_OFF = "GPS_TURNED_OFF"
}}
```

My Observable

```
class ObservableGpsState: Observable(){

fun updateValue(data: Any) {
    synchronized(this) {
        setChanged()
        notifyObservers(data)
    }
}
companion object {
    private val instance = ObservableGpsState()
    fun getInstance(): ObservableGpsState {
        return instance
    }
}}
```

And (what I guess) is important from my Activity:

```
protected lateinit var observer: Observable

private fun registerGpsObserver(){
    observer = ObservableGpsState.getInstance()
    observer.addObserver(this)
}
private fun unregisterGpsObserver(){
    observer.deleteObserver(this)
}

override fun update(o: Observable?, arg: Any?) {
    MyApplication.get(baseContext).enableGpsDialog(this)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that this issue arises only on some devices (though I am not 100% sure about it, but it is the case when listening to network changes via a `BroadcastReceiver` so it would make sense).

Anyway the simplest solution would be to Make an `enum` which holds the current `State` of your `GPS`. Only if the **State changes notify the Observer**. This way the `onReceive` could be called 1000 times but your `Observer` gets notified only once.

Comment: How I could achiev this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved with :

```
 BroadcastReceiver gpsSwitchStateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    //here you can check your current state when instanciate it.
        boolean oldLocationEnabled = isLocationSystemEnabled();

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            try {
                String action;
                if (intent != null && (action = intent.getAction()) != null && action.matches(LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION)) {
                    boolean locationEnabled = isLocationSystemEnabled();
//this validation ensures that it is executed only once (since the receiver is executed in the UIThread) 
                    if (oldLocationEnabled != locationEnabled) {
                        if (locationEnabled) {
                        //your code here 
                        } else {
                        //when dont have location here
                        }
                    }
                    oldLocationEnabled = locationEnabled;
                }
            } catch (Exception ignored) {}
        }
    };

public boolean isLocationSystemEnabled() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) ApplicationLoader.appContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean         isGPSEnabled    = false;
        boolean         isNetEnabled    = false;
        if (locationManager != null) {
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            isNetEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        }
        return isGPSEnabled || isNetEnabled;
    } else {
        String allowedLocationProviders = Settings.System.getString(ApplicationLoader.appContext.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
        if (allowedLocationProviders == null) {
            allowedLocationProviders = "";
        }
        return allowedLocationProviders.contains(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple location providers in Android. Therefore, the event you are listening to corresponds to provider changes, and not to location activation. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6775456/13941008.

Use `LocationManager.MODE_CHANGED_ACTION` instead and retrieve the current location activation status using `LocationManager.EXTRA_LOCATION_ENABLED` directly from the `Intent` argument. Example:

```kotlin
val locationListener = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
   override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent) {
      when(val action = intent.action){
         LocationManager.MODE_CHANGED_ACTION -> {
            val locationState = intent.getBooleanExtra(
               LocationManager.EXTRA_LOCATION_ENABLED,
               false
            )
          // Do something using locationState variable
          } else -> {
             Log.d(TAG, "Unsupported action received $action")
          }
      }
   }
}

val intentFilter = IntentFilter(LocationManager.MODE_CHANGED_ACTION)
context.registerReceiver(locationListener, intentFilter)
```

Finally, do not forget to unregister the receiver when it is no longer needed. Example:

```kotlin
context.unregisterReceiver(locationListener)
```